# Ban web application to download bootstrap and jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application. When I deploy it, it shouldn't download any libraries or anything from the internet (for example bootstrap and jquery). I want to have them locally and use them. How can I achieve that?

My progress:

I have found out that in _Layout.cshtml there is this piece of code:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

Is it safe to only copy the content of Development scripts into Staging,Production? Is it some other solution to this problem?

Comment: Why? That might matter. Using the standard CDNs is very much preferable because of the per browser caching.

Comment: When I deploy the application it does not have access to other websites so when the user access it, he has to wait few minutes until it timeouts...

Comment: Do your end-users have access to the internet? That's (very) different from the access your server has or doesn't have.

Comment: No they don't have access to the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you really need it internal (maybe in a shielded IntraNet) then you should set up your own CDN (-alike) URL and place the minified (`.min.js`) versions  there. Try to reuse that location in all your in-company sites.

As you have seen, it's very easy to point any Edition (Environment) to any place you want.

Comment: So I can download both minified versions from <script> tag and then just reference it like <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>?

Comment: Yes, that ought to work. But like I said, `~/lib` is not the best location, especially when you have more than one internal site.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. Why is it not the best location? Because of the unnecessary copies of these libs in each of the application I have? Or is there any other reason?

Comment: Yes, the "unnecessary copies" also lead to unnecessary copies in the cache of each Browser. Look up the what and why of CDN.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a user `ASP CORE`, just `ASP MVC` but i think's with `ASP.CORE` you have access to npm. If you have access to npm use this. If not create file `jquery.js` and reference this in your layout (or in your bunble)